# CORS won't let me log in

Tags: firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions, cors

I'm building with React and Firebase.
I have an app(mysite.com) where the code for app resides and cloud functions. I developed another app(admin.mysite.com) which is a backend. They both point to the same project.

I created a callable functions deployed through mysite.com to the project but called in the admin website. I've been having CORS problems with these. I've discovered(but not tested yet) how to set cloud functions so no CORS errors. My issue is that CORS has now blocked me from authenticating in the admin website.

> Access to fetch at
> 'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=...'
> from origin 'admin.mysite.com' has been blocked by CORS
> policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control
> check: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header has a value
> 'mysite.com' that is not equal to the supplied origin. Have
> the server send the header with a valid value, or, if an opaque
> response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to
> fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

I understand that the two header origins are not the same, i just don't know how to correct it. I tried making corrections to the firebase.json file according to the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/full-config#headers).

```
"hosting": {
  // ...

  // Applies a CORS header for all font files
  "headers": [ {
    "source": "**/*.@(eot|otf|ttf|ttc|woff|font.css)",
    "headers": [ {
      "key": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin",
      "value": "*"
    } ]
  } ]
}
```

But its not working.

How do i fix headers in both sites so that i can authenticate?